# create byte array from set of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, concatenation, bit-manipulation

Given these integers:

```
public uint ServerSequenceNumber;
public uint Reserved1;
public uint Reserved2;
public byte Reserved3;
public byte TotalPlayers;
```

What's the best way to create a `byte[]` array from them?  If all their values are `1` the resulting array would be:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001 00000000000000000000000000000001 00000000000000000000000000000001 00000001 00000001
```

Comment: byte array or bit array?  You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa311381%28v=vs.71%29.aspx to get a byte array, and then you would have to swap the bytes around for endianness.

Comment: What have you tried, and why do you need a byte array, what's it for? Making them properties, decorating them with an attribute and then writing decorated poperties in order to a stream and then grabbing that as an array could be the best way, certainly is would be reusable as an extension or an interface.

Comment: @Tony it's for a real time multiplayer game, it's a message from the server sent to all clients updating the game state.  I've managed to get the correct array from loops but my method was too slow.  Was just wondering what the best practise is for this as I don't have much experience with this sort of thing

Comment: Some of your resutling array values are larger than 8 bits, so they won't fit into a byte array. Are you trying to create an in memory image that looks like that stream of bytes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what your looking for. BitConverter returns a byte array in the order of endianness of the processor being used. For x86 processors it is little-endian. This places the least significant byte first.

```
 int value;
 byte[] byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
 Array.Reverse(byte);
 byte[] result = byte;
```

If you don't know the processor your going to be using the app on I suggest using:

```
int value;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian){
Array.Reverse(bytes);
}
byte[] result = bytes;
```

Comment: +1, but it doesn't create a "backwards" array, `BitConverter` returns a byte array in the order of endianness of the processor being used, which happens to be little-endian on x86 processors (least significant byte first).

Comment: @Robert thanks works great, I've added my own answer based on yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/14464592/356635

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[14];
int i = 0;
foreach(uint num in new uint[]{SecureSequenceNumber, Reserved1, Reserved2})
{
    bytes[i] = (byte)(num >> 24);
    bytes[i + 1] = (byte)(num >> 16);
    bytes[i + 2] = (byte)(num >> 8);
    bytes[i + 3] = (byte)num;
    i += 4;
}
bytes[12] = Reserved3;
bytes[13] = TotalPlayers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Robert's answer I created a simple class that makes things neater when you're doing lots of concatanations:

```
class ByteJoiner
{
    private int i;
    public byte[] Bytes { get; private set; }

    public ByteJoiner(int totalBytes)
    {
        i = 0;
        Bytes = new byte[totalBytes];
    }

    public void Add(byte input)
    {
        Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(input));
    }
    public void Add(uint input)
    {
        Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(input));
    }
    public void Add(ushort input)
    {
        Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(input));
    }
    public void Add(byte[] input)
    {
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, Bytes, i, input.Length);
        i += input.Length;
    }
}
```